# Excel NetWorkdays() Built in function fails in Japanese PC

Tags: excel, excel-formula, regional-settings

There are couple of Excel tools used in English based systems. However when same tools are used in Japanese systems, specifically `NetWorkdays()` Excel function doesn't seem to work -- it simply shows `#NA` in the cell.

Has anyone out there encountered similar issues? If so please share how you fixed it.

PS: Does it mean "Analysis Tookpak" has no support for a PC with Japanese Lan & Reg Settings?

Comment: Not having a Japense system handy, define `doesn't seem to work`

Comment: Fine, PC, system, whatever, I'm aware you're testing on multiple systems, no need to be rude.  I was merely asking "what doesn't work", since you don't specify how exactly the function doesn't work.

Comment: Do you mean NETWORKDAYS worksheet function (rather than NETWORKINGDAYS which is probably a UDF)? Are you using the correct function - I don't think there's a translation for Japanese, English version should work.....

Comment: @barryhoudini precisely "NetworkDays()" Excel built in function. I am not referring to a UDF. English version works well. I am checking if .intl is created to Support Japanese Lan & Reg settings or not. Thanks for pointing out the typo.. ;)

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables well the way you commented was rather putting a "fullstop" for someone searching for a positive route or solution... Error simply give "#Name".

Comment: No rudeness intended, it's just very offputting for a user with over 7000 rep to simply state "it doesn't seem to work", as opposed to showing the full function you're using (including inputs) as well as the error you're getting.  Best of luck to you.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables no hard feelings mate! Bingo, reckon you would comeback with ref to my reps. Anyways I agree with you, for having lack of info on the question body. To be frank, there's really not much to write. Coz it simply works in 10 other languages. But for Japanese. I have also checked [here](http://en.excel-translator.de/networkdays/)

Comment: @bonCodigo, have you tried converting dates to the American mm/dd/yyyy format before running them through the function? (I'm just guessing here.)

Answer (score 0):

Does the newer `NETWORKDAYS.INTL` function help? See [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/networkdays-intl-function-HA010354379.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA010355760)

Comment: Thanks barrowc. We tried what you mentioned, no luck as of now. Unless something is a miss...sorry for late reply.